# ¿Cómo enviar el OperID a la API REST de Redsys?

Tags: php, api, rest

Estoy desarrollando una pasarela de pago con Redsys utilizando la **integración InSite** para captar los datos de la tarjeta del cliente con seguridad y, después, la **API REST** de Redsys para generar los pagos recurrentes.

La aplicación aún se encuentra en el entorno de pruebas (*Sandbox*).

La primera parte (InSite) funciona correctamente y genera el ID de la operación (`OperID`) con éxito.

Pero al enviar una solicitud de pago mediante el método `$request->setOperID($operID)` la API devuelve el error:

> SIS0502: Error al validar Id Oper.

Tanto la integración InSite como la API REST están utilizando los mismos parámetros obligatorios: Nº de comercio, Nº de terminal y Nº de pedido.

No encuentro más información en la [documentación oficial de Redsys](https://pagosonline.redsys.es/modelos-de-integracion.html).

Answer (score 0):

no se está realizando correctamente la firma. Fíjate que tengas correctamente los datos de la clave de comercio y el número del mismo. Redsys provee una librería en php que facilita mucho la realización de la firma.